# How to add custom annotations with uncertainty to a heatmap

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, heatmap, plot-annotations

I am attempting to visualize some data as a table, where the boxes of each table element are colored according to their value, the numerical value is also displayed, and the uncertainty on each element is shown. I can achieve 2 out of these 3 things using `pandas.pivot_table` and `sns.heatmap`, but cannot seem to include the uncertainty on each table element as part of the annotation. In the example code snippet:

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo",
                         "bar", "bar", "bar", "bar"],
                   "B": ["one", "one", "one", "two", "two",
                         "one", "one", "two", "two"],
                   "C": ["small", "large", "large", "small",
                         "small", "large", "small", "small",
                         "large"],
                   "D": [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                   "E": [2, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9, 9]})

table = pd.pivot_table(df, values='D', index=['A', 'B'],
                       columns=['C'], aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value=0)

sns.heatmap(table,annot=True)
```

we produce a table like so:

[image: seaborn heatmap of a pandas pivot_table]

However, imagine that the entries `"E"` represented the uncertainty on elements `"D"`. Is there any way these can be displayed on the table, as `"E"[i]+/-"D"[i]`? I tried using a custom annotation grid, but this requires a `numpy` array and so string formatting each element didn't work for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a DataFrame with the formatted strings to [`sns.heatmap`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html):

```py
table = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['D', 'E'], index=['A', 'B'],
                       columns=['C'], aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value=0)

sns.heatmap(table['D'],
            annot=table['D'].astype(str)+'±'+table['E'].astype(str),
            fmt='')
```

[image]